# How to set a 0 result in meta_search before user pressing a search button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I'm using a meta_search on my rails 3 app. By default (before pressing a search button) meta_search returns all elements of searching model. and I want to set 0 result before user pressing a search button or if search params is blank.

I am using meta_search as follows:

```
def index
 @search = Article.search(params[:search])
  if params[:search].blank?
    @places = nil
  else
    @places = @search.all
  end
end
```

What is the best way to set a 0 result if search params is blank ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's something that Meta Search really provides out of the box but you can always cheat it.

```
def index
  @search = Article.search(params[:search].presence || {:id_lt => 0})
  @places = @search.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your solution is good enough. It's clear about what it's doing and it doesn't access the database unnecessarily. But the code can be improved to:

```
def index
  @search = Article.search(params[:search])
  @places = @search.search_attributes.values.all?(&:blank?) ? [] : @search.all
end
```

Checking the hash for blank is not the way to do it. A hash like `{'name_contains' => ''}`, which is what you get if the form submitted is blank, will return `false`.

Also it's better to set `@places` to an empty array rather than `nil`. This way you don't have to check for `nil` and your loop will still work.

Comment: Yeah you are very right about setting nil object to instance  variable `@places`, 
and thank you very much! I really appreciate this help )))