# Return 0 records metasearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, meta-search

I am on Rails 3.1 and I am using the [Ransack Gem](https://github.com/ernie/ransack). This is what I have in my controller:

```
@q = Person.search(params[:q])
@people = @q.result
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <label>Given Name:</label>
  <%= f.text_field :given_name_cont %>

  <label>Family Name:</label>
  <%= f.text_field :family_name_cont %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This works well and is per the Ransack documentation. However, if my search form does not contain any parameters (ie nothing specified to search) it returns *ALL* records. What I want to have happen is *NO* records returned.

My Ruby is pretty weak so can someone show me how to cleanly have @people return an empty array if there is no params[:q] or params[:q] does not specify any search criteria (ie the user submitted an empty form).

Essentially my question is the same as this [Metasearch question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827910/how-to-set-a-0-result-in-meta-search-before-user-pressing-a-search-button), but the solution doesn't seem to work for Ransack as it complains "search_attributes" is not an available method.

It's important that it returns 0 records with no params submitted and with empty params submitted. Any notes explaining why your code works would be good to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your controller code with:

```
if !params[:q].blank?  # nil.blank? and [].blank? are true
  @q = Person.search(params[:q])
  @people = @q.result 
else
  @people = []
end
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly. The explanation of # nil.blank? and [].blank? was also helpful.