# Preventing the search to happen checking the value of the search input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the `meta_search` gem to search products in my catalog. However, the first time I enter the search page or I send a blank value, the search is made and all the products are returned and listed.

I am trying to prevent this checking that the value of the search input is not `nil` or `""` so the search is performed only when something is actually typed in the text field.

This is my `search.html.erb` file:

```
<%= render :partial => 'search_box' %>
<% if @products %>
    <p>The search "<%= params[:search][:name_contains] %>" returned <%= pluralize @products.size, "result" %>:</p>
    <%= render(:partial => "products") %>
<% end %>
```

`_search_box.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => "/catalog/search", :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Name %>  
  <%= f.text_field :name_contains %>
  <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

The `search` method of the `CatalogController`:

```
  def search
    if params[:search]
      @search = Product.search(params[:search])
      @products = @search.all
      unless @products.size > 0
        flash.now[:notice] = "No results"
      end
    end
  end
```

When I browse to `/catalog/search` I get the following error:

```
 NoMethodError in Catalog#search

Showing /*****/app/views/catalog/_search_box.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @search, :url => "/catalog/search", :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.label :Nombre %> 
3:   <%= f.text_field :name_contains %>
4:   <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
```

Comment: because when your params search blank then @search is nil. why are you using form_for here. just use form_tag simply

Comment: there are a couple of ways you can do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827910/how-to-set-a-0-result-in-meta-search-before-user-pressing-a-search-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and i think in this way your @search will always be found

```
def search
  @search = Product.search(params[:search])
  if params[:search]
    @products = @search.all
    flash.now[:notice] = "No results" unless @products.size > 0
   end
end
```

Comment: the `meta_search` gem works with the names of the fields. it needs to be `form_for` so it creates a hash in `search`

Comment: Then you can do one thing here if your params search is blank then simply initialize your Product model like this @search = Product.new. i hope this should work

Comment: where should I do that? in the controller?